# How to incorporate blocking code into Mutiny using reactive-messaging

Tags: jdbc, mutiny, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I wanted to get an opinion on how to properly implement this and if this is the right approach to doing so. So I have created a fully reactive application using reactive-messaging but have come to know that I have an overarching constraint - and that constraint being Oracle. As you know, JDBC is inherently blocking in nature and cannot *really* be executed asynchronously. I am trying to figure out a way to achieve this so that the event loop thread does not get blocked and so far the only thing that *seems* to work is something like this:

```
@Incoming(KAFKA_DATA)
@Blocking
@Acknowledgment(Acknowledgment.Strategy.MANUAL)
fun consume(record: Message<Notification>): CompletionStage<Void> {
    val metadata = record.getMetadata(IncomingKafkaRecordMetadata::class.java).orElse(null)
    if (metadata != null) {
        log.debug(
            "Received Kafka Record - " +
                "topic: {}, " +
                "partition: {}, " +
                "offset: {}, " +
                "payload: {}",
            metadata.topic, metadata.partition, metadata.offset, record.payload
        )
    }
    return Uni.createFrom().voidItem()
        .invoke { -> invokeBlockingCall(record.payload) }
        .call { -> handleSuccess(record) }
        .onFailure().call { failure -> handleFailure(failure, record) }
        .runSubscriptionOn(Infrastructure.getDefaultExecutor())
        .subscribeAsCompletionStage()
}
```

I have managed to get that working as-is but I am unsure if it is the correct/efficient way of doing so. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve such a task? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated and taken into account, thanks!

Comment: Oracle may not be a constraint anymore. There is a non-blocking driver developed here: https://vertx.io/docs/4.2.0/vertx-oracle-client/java/.

In your snippet, you can remove the @Blocking, as you call the blocking method on a worker thread.

Comment: Understood. I have removed the @Blocking annotation as that makes sense to me, was just unsure if it had to be used in-tandem with blocking calls. For the reactive oracle client, do you know if it integrates with Mutiny? If so, is there an example of such code? I am still new to reactive and learning as I go.

Comment: If you are using Quarkus, there is an extension for it and yes, we have a Mutiny API for it. You can find the Javadoc here: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny-vertx-bindings/2.17.0/apidocs/io/vertx/mutiny/oracleclient/package-summary.html. It's the same API as the other reactive datasource.

Comment: Starting with the 21.1 release, Oracle JDBC now includes Reactive Extensions for asynchronous non-blocking database calls: docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/… You can also check out the Oracle R2DBC project, which is an open source implementation built on top of the Reactive Extensions: github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc I worked on both of these projects, so I'm biased in thinking they are both great solutions :)

Comment: @MichaelMcMahon Yes I was actually thinking of looking into that! Would you be able to guide me further by helping me with maybe a sample proof-of-concept project or code so that I may get a better understanding of how to implement it in my project?

Comment: @LazaroR. For Oracle JDBC's Reactive Extensions, you can find some code examples in the developers guide:
[Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjdbc/jdbc-reactive-extensions.html#GUID-1C40C43B-3823-4848-8B5A-D2F97A82F79B)
And for Oracle R2DBC, the R2DBC Specification is good place to start, and has many code examples:
[R2DBC Spec](https://r2dbc.io/spec/0.9.0.RELEASE/spec/html/)
We also have some Oracle specific code examples here:
[Oracle Examples](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-r2dbc/tree/main/sample/src/main/java/oracle/r2dbc/samples)

Comment: I would recommend not using R2DBC in Quarkus. You would not be able to use most of the features of Quarkus with that model. Quarkus provides its own reactive Oracle client.

Comment: Clement, I have seen that Quarkus 2.7.x has integrated the reactive-oracle-client and marked as "experimental" in the docs. I have been trying to implement that but cannot seem to get any transaction inserted into the database due to this error: `HR000061: Session is currently connecting to database`. Feel free to check the issue out on Quarkus GH: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23736